# Unable to destroy activity Android: Google Play Console Error

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to launch my app into Production on Google Playstore. I have used Flutter to create the app. But in the pre-launch report I am getting error:

```
Stacktrace: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.stech.ebox_expenses/com.example.ebox_expenses.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.e.c(androidx.lifecycle.h)' on a null object reference

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.stech.ebox_expenses, PID: 12391
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.stech.ebox_expenses/com.example.ebox_expenses.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.e.c(androidx.lifecycle.h)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4504)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4522)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1697)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6647)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.e.c(androidx.lifecycle.h)' on a null object reference
    at com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerPlugin.j(Unknown Source:21)
    at com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerPlugin.e(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.c.h(Unknown Source:54)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.o(Unknown Source:58)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.G(Unknown Source:7)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.onDestroy(Unknown Source:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7241)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4491)
    ... 9 more
```

I try to find anything discussing this and I found one Stackoverflow question which was recieved badly and downvoted; Here's a ref to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65074829/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-destroy-activity-java-lang-runtimeexcepti). I am not to sure why this is happening and I am not sure whether it is external problem which I can fix or an internal bug.

When I downloaded the app from the Playstore when it was production, it displayed a white screen when I opened it and stayed like this. I am not sure if me getting this error is a result of that or not either.

Any help on the matter will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix both problems which I was having. I fixed the first problem of this error by updating `file_picker` library to version `2.10`. The issue was fixed in version `2.0.12`. I also fixed the second issue of the white screen in the app when it started by downgrading to: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'`. Here's the reference to the post which helped me.